# Dar formato a tipos personalizados en ostream

Tags: c++, ostream

Es posible modificar el comportamiento de un stream con diferentes opciones, por ejemplo:

```
std::cout << 0xfabadau << '\n';
std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(8) << 0xfabadau << '\n';
```

Muestra:

> ```
> 16431834
> 00fabada
> ```

Ahora supongamos que tengo un tipo personalizado `byte_buffer`:

```
using byte        = std::uint8_t;
using byte_buffer = std::vector<byte>;

std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const byte_buffer &buffer)
{
    for (const auto &b : buffer) o << std::hex << int{b};
    return o << std::dec;
}
```

Al usarlo, no puedo aplicar el formato personalizado:

```
byte_buffer b { 0xfau, 0xbau, 0xdau, };
std::cout << b << '\n';
std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(8) << b << '\n';
```

El código anterior muestra:

> ```
> fabada
> 000000fabada
> ```

El `std::setfill` y `std::setw` de **fuera** del `std::ostream &operator <<` se ha aplicado sobre el primer `byte` de `byte_buffer` **dentro** del `std::ostream &operator <<` dando lugar al formato que vemos. Esto no es inesperado, pero no es lo deseado. La salida que querría es:

> ```
> fabada
> 00fabada
> ```

---

¿De qué manera debo modificar el `std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const byte_buffer &buffer)` para que `byte_buffer` se comporte de la manera que espero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema que tiene tu código es que estás insertando cada elemento de forma independiente. Tendrías que agrupar el contenido del tipo antes de volcarlo al stream para que se aplicase la configuración correctamente.

Esto se puede conseguir fácilmente con `stringstream`. `stringstream` puede ser configurado de igual manera que `cout`, por lo que podemos seguir utilizando los modificadores de `iomanip`.

La mecánica sería la siguiente:

Se vuelca el contenido del nuevo tipo a un stream de tipo `stringstream`. Una vez hecho esto se vuelca el contenido de este stream al stream de salida, de esta forma sólo se envía un elemento y es dicho elemento el que recibe la configuración que se ha realizado fuera de la especialización del operador de inserción:

```
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const byte_buffer &buffer)
{
  std::stringstream stream;
  for (const auto &b : buffer)
    stream << std::hex << static_cast<int>(b);

  return o << stream.str();
}

int main()
{
  byte_buffer b { 0xfau, 0xbau, 0xdau, };
  std::cout << b << '\n';
  std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(8);
  std::cout << b << '\n';
}
```